# KDE 16.04: different user, different language?

Tags: kubuntu, kde

Good day.  I am using Kubuntu 16.04, which I installed in English.  I prefer my account in English (admin account), while a friend of mine who uses the same PC would like to have her account in Italian (not an admin account).  We somehow couldn't figure out a way to change her account's language to Italian; related forums seem dated.  I would greatly appreciate help!

Comment: Have you found the answer to your question? Does existing answer help?

Answer (score 0):

While you're logged into the other account

1. Open **System Settings**
2. Click on **Regional Settings**
3. On the new page, while **Translations** Tab is selected
4. Select the language on the **Available Languages** list and then click on the <kbd>></kbd> button to move it to the **Preferred Languages** list.
5. Logout and Log in again to see the effect.